# How can I include values from text boxes that are not NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that gets the value from text boxes and inserts them into the database.
How can I parse the values from only text boxes which have had text typed into them?

For example if textbox 4, 5  6 are empty then I do not want them to be parsed to the insert method.

This is what I have written to insert ONE answer into the database. How can I modify it to include only those text boxes that are NOT null?

```
<div id="answer_wrapper">
                <div class="answer">
                    <h3 class="new">Answer 1</h3>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- end answer -->
                <div class="answer">
                    <h3 class="new">Answer 2</h3>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- end answer -->
                <div class="answer">
                    <h3 class="new">Answer 3</h3>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerBox3" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- end answer -->
                <div class="answer">
                    <h3 class="new">Answer 4</h3>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerBox4" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- end answer -->
                <div class="answer">
                    <h3 class="new">Answer 5</h3>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerBox5" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- end answer -->
                <div class="answer">
                    <h3 class="new">Answer 6</h3>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerBox6" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- end answer -->
```

```
protected void FinishQnrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int QuestionnaireId = (int)Session["QuestionnaireID"];  
            SendData = new OsqarSQL();
            int questionId = SendData.InsertQuestions(QuestionName.Text, Int32.Parse(QuestnType.SelectedValue), QuestionnaireId);
            int answerId = SendData.InsertAnswer(AnswerBox1.Text, questionId, QuestionnaireId);
            Response.Redirect("~/buildq/Confirm_Questionnaire.aspx");

        } // End NewQNRButton_Click

        public int InsertAnswer(string AnswerTitle, int QuestionID, int QuestionnaireID)
        {
            int returnValue = 0;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("NewAnswer", _productConn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ANSWERTITLE", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUESTION_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUEST_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ANSWER_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ANSWER_ID");
            myCommand.Parameters["@ANSWER_ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = AnswerTitle;
            myCommand.Parameters[1].Value = QuestionID;
            myCommand.Parameters[2].Value = QuestionnaireID;
            _productConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            returnValue = (int)myCommand.Parameters["@ANSWER_ID"].Value;
            _productConn.Close();
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: Note that a `textbox.Text` property value will *never* be null. I surmise that string.Empty (or even just *whitespace*) is what you are really trying to avoid.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly You could test a text box .Text value property with string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerBox4.Text) and decide upon that

Comment: what probelm or error are you having..? looks like you will also need to have a DBNull assignment as part of the Parameter values if you are not checking for them.. also change myCommand.Parameters to myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the `TextBox.Text` property will never be `null`.  If no value is present in the form, it will be `string.Empty`.

You can test for empty strings with something like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnswerBox1.Text))
    int answerId = SendData.InsertAnswer(AnswerBox1.Text, questionId, QuestionnaireId);
```

Note that I'm not *entirely* sure what your overall goal here is.  Maybe I'm missing something.  It *sounds* like you're asking how to check each `TextBox` for empty values and perform an insert on the ones which have non-empty values.  So I guess you'd do something similar to the above several times.  There are other ways to do it, you can wrap it all in helper methods, etc.  But in general you're just testing for a "non-insertable according to the business rules" value.

Comment: Thanks. I used this and it is working now.
Is there anyway I can condense the code? As it seems a little bloated. Or am I just being fussy?

Comment: @Rupert: More than likely.  You can identify patterns and re-factor accordingly.  It's not really being fussy, it's just wanting to keep your code clean and expressive (which is always a worth-while goal).  I'd hold off on the re-factoring until the functionality is achieved, just in case you need to change anything else along the way.  You might try going to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to help with cleaning it up.  (But check their FAQ first, I'm no expert on what's considered on-topic there.)